# Best way to avoid multiple conflict resolutions - Git soft reset before rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, squash

Whenever I have a complicated rebase because there are a lot of conclicts with my current feature branch and because my feature branch has lots of small commits, the resolution process seems troublesome and inefficient.

I've been looking for ways to essentialy squash `before` the rebase happens. One solution seems to be to do a sofr reset to the last merge and then create one single commit out of the many commits, and only then do the rebase.

But this solution seems a bit hacky. Is there a better way to handle this.

EDIT:
I'm referring to cases where a merge has to be done via pull request and I have no control over the merge process itself.

Comment: Your question will be easier to understand if you also include git commands to go along with your English description.

Comment: Won't a simple interactive rebase where you squash everything fix this? You're not getting conflicts on the branch alone are you? Meaning that individual commits on that branch are in conflicts with other commits on the same branch?

Comment: Yes but does the squash not only happen after the rebase? In order to avoid the multiple conflicts, don't I have to squash before the rebase happens? Otherwise it will still replay each commit and ask me to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Interactive rebase with squash should keep the parent of the initial commit, unless you ask it to also rebase on top of something.

Comment: so I need to do an interactive rebase (without rebaseing it on something) first and only then a rebase?

Comment: If you have lots of commits then I guess your `reset --soft` workflow is faster than `rebase -i`. During the interactive rebase you have to actively mark all but one commit with `s` (for squash) which seems tedious to do for, say, 30 commits. You might want to do the `soft --rebase` on a new branch based off your feature branch so you can always easily go back to the original (`reflog` would also be possible but it's easier this way).

Comment: An interactive rebase does not seem to be the same like a soft reset as in all the GUIs I've tried it is a requirement to pick the first commit. Yes, I can then squash the following commits, but it will still require me to go through each of them and resolve the conflicts separately. Any opinions? Did I do something wrong? I tried intellij and tortoise git.

Comment: Doing a soft reset will not avoid merge conflicts. You will just have to deal with them all at once.When you finally rebase the squashed commit.

Comment: Yes, but I won't have to deal with the same conflicts multiple times, if multiple commits made changes in a file that is in conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A soft reset to the last merge and then create a single new commit is the best solution. This has been heavily downvoted but I don't think this is justified, especially in cases where it's not possible to do a merge to master directly, as it has to be done via pull request.

Comment: I agree that this is a viable option. Not sure who downvoted this.

Comment: I will downvote an answer of the form "X is the best solution" with literally no explanation or arguments to support that statement any day.

Comment: That’s a bit odd. Downvote so I google it for you? I still think it’s the best answer but I have no academic literature on it

Answer (score 4):

As you've worked out in the comments, you probably want the `git rebase -i` work-flow.

Running `git rebase -i <commit-to-keep>` essentially tells Git:

1. list commits that are on the current branch, that come after `<commit-to-keep>`;
2. bring up and instruction sheet saying to `pick <hash>` for every such commit;
3. once the instruction sheet is edited, check out `<commit-to-keep>` and then follow the instructions;
4. upon completing the instructions, make the current branch point to the last such copied (or squashed or whatever) commit.

Hence, if you have a series of tiny commits `A1, A2, A3` and then some more `B1, B2`, such as:

```
...--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         \
          A1--A2--A3--B1--B2   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and run `git rebase -i origin/feature`, Git will list all five commit hashes as `pick` instructions.  Changing the `A2` and `A3` instructions to `squash`, and also changing the `B2` instruction to `squash`, and saving the resulting command sequence, causes Git to start pick-and-squash-ing commits.  Git stops for a bit at the last of the `A` group to let you edit the commit message, bringing up your editor on the message for new commit `A` that is `A1+A2+A3`:

```
          A   <-- HEAD [in progress / being rebuilt]
         /
...--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         \
          A1--A2--A3--B1--B2   <-- feature [being rebased]
```

It now automatically resumes the list, which is down to the instructions for the `B` commits.  It pauses again, launching your editor, for committing the new all-in-one `B`:

```
          A--B   <-- HEAD [in progress / being rebuilt]
         /
...--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         \
          A1--A2--A3--B1--B2   <-- feature [being rebased]
```

Once you've edited the commit message, it resumes yet again and finalizes the branch update by "peeling the label" `feature` off the old chain and sticking it onto the new one:

```
          A--B   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         \
          A1--A2--A3--B1--B2   [abandoned - in reflog as feature@{1}]
```

Note that if there are conflicts, Git pauses the rebasing with a much bigger pause (it actually exits the `git rebase` command entirely, but leaves a lot of trace files behind that `git status` can use to show that you're still in the middle of the rebase).  You must fix the conflicts and run `git rebase --continue` to resume things.  If you're just squashing some commits down, you should not see conflicts, but if you're re-arranging a bunch of scattered small ones—i.e., instead of having all your `A` group together initially, they *were* scattered around, and you gathered them together—you may have small conflicts to resolve.

---

Running `git rebase -i` with no arguments tells Git to look up the current branch's "upstream" setting.  For instance, if `feature` which has `origin/feature` as its upstream, this is equivalent to `git rebase -i origin/feature`.  You're always copying your selected / edited-TODO-list commits to come after some specified commit, but the default is "the upstream you've already set".

Note that you would have to do all this *before* running `git fetch`, since `git fetch` would update `origin/feature`.  If you did run `git fetch`, and it did update `origin/feature`, you may now have:

```
          o--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         /
...--o--*   [remembered in your reflogs as origin/feature@{1}]
         \
          A1--A2--A3--B1--B2   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If this is the case, you'll need to explicitly `git rebase -i` upon commit `*`.  You can find its hash by running `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` (using "help from A DOG", All Decorate Oneline Graph), or you can use the fact that it's in your `origin/feature` reflog as `origin/feature@{1}`, verifying that with:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph origin/feature@{1}..
```

(The "DOG" is still in there, just not the `--all` part, to cut down on clutter.  Or, you could even use `git merge-base` to locate commit `*`, but we'll leave that for another topic. :-) )

Comment: you say: ". If you're just squashing some commits down, you should not see conflicts". But in fact I do see conflicts and it shows me the first pick (which is the first commit) to resolve, but I only want the last state to resolve.

Comment: @Nickpick: For this to happen, you *must* be doing something more than just squashing-down, e.g., actually-rebasing. Use the "help from A DOG" I described above to find out what your graph looks like before running `git rebase -i`.

Comment: I see, so I need to rebase on the copy of the branch on the origin first, which is essentially rebasing on itself before doing the actual rebae? Not very pretty at all! Is there no way to do it all in one go?

Comment: Correct: the problem is that by trying to do it in one pass, you have to resolve the conflicts in the first group of commits (such asthe "A" series) one at a time as you go, and your goal was to resolve them just once (after the "A" series becomes a single commit `A`).  You could write a rebase-like program that does things "in parallel" (copies and squashes on the original base for the original A-series to get a single A, then copies that onto the new base), but it's not built in to Git.

Comment: Instead of rebasing on the origin, couldn't I rebase on the local branch itself? At least that's safer I think.

Comment: Rebase doesn't actually care about branch *names* at all, except for the current branch. It only cares about commit hashes. (At the end it has to move the current branch's name to point to the final copied commit, and that's the one place it really needs a name.) So you can use anything that resolves to the correct hash.

Comment: That’s all a bit disappointing and too complicated. I think a soft reset is actually the best solution. But just sounds all a bit clumsy. Is there nobody writing a rapper around git for those obvious things that need some implementation?

Comment: Soft reset is good for collapsing everything to a single commit. Interactive rebase is good for re-grouping and fixing-up commits. In fact, there's an "autosquash" mode for interactive rebase to deal with this: you make squash-able or fix-style commits with `git commit --fixup <commit>` or `git commit --squash <commit>`, and then run `git rebase -i --autosquash` and you get pre-assembled instructions. As for writing your own automated wrappers, feel free to have at it: Git is open source. A lot of what's in there now is because someone wanted it and wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git merge --squash feature_branch`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature_branch
```

This will take all the commits from `feature_branch` squash them into one commit and and add this one commit to `master`.

#### Example

The following repo has a branch `feature/1` which was based of `master`. There are some commits in `feature/1` and one on `master`. After that I did a `git merge --squash feature/1` on `master` which created commit `5497776` that contains the changes from the tree commits on `feature/1`.

```
* 5497776 (HEAD, master) merge --squash feature/1
* 46059c7 Change 2 on master
| * b080e96 (feature/1) Change 3 on feature branch
| * 6caf662 Change 2 on feature branch
| * 69d9993 Change 1 on feature branch
|/  
* b39b078 Change 1
```

By the way, I explicitly provoked merge conflicts. You can resolve them during the merge process, then stage the changes to mark the conflicts as resolved and continue with `git commit`.

Comment: Yes but I need to rebase before I merge, so this won't work

Comment: Maybe I have understood your question wrong, but you noted that you wanted to squash all of your commit into **one** before rebasing it on top of your `master` branch. This is exactly what `merge --sqash` does, even though we are using a `merge` command. As you can see the top most commit `5497776` is on top of the latest commit `46059c7` on `master`. This is what a `rebase` usually does. If you wanted to group your small commits on your feature branch into bigger ones, you'd need rebase, but not if it is only into one single commit.

Comment: Yes but in our company we are required to rebase

Comment: I don't think you are required to use actual `rebase` command but are required to not introduce merge commits to have a linear history. `merge --squash` does not introduce merge commits. The end result is exactly the same as with `rebase`. No one could ever tell how this commit was created.

Comment: yes it will be visible because the merge is configured to use --no-ff

Comment: Have you ever tried it? The option `git config --add merge.ff false` doesn't affect `merge --squash`, I've just tried it.  BTW if you explicitly set it like this `git merge --squash --no-ff`, it gives you `fatal: You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff.`. This command still doesn't create a merge commit (and yes, the squash functionality shouldn't be part of `merge` command, but it is what it is).

Comment: This example does not work when you have to go through code review via pull request

Comment: You are right. However, I also like to point out that you could create a temporary local branch off your feature branch and work on that. After the work done you can merge squash into the original feature branch and create a pull request. Remember branching is cheap in Git. Additionally, you save your intermediate commits in the temp branch (in the soft reset case you'd need to use reflog to restore the commits). I use this workflow when working with git-svn since you can't use merge commits there neither, see https://labs.consol.de/git/development/2015/06/23/git-merge-squash.html

Comment: I have to add, that I was thinking to fast. Of course, you need to create a new branch from the latest `master` and merge squash your temp branch to that and then create the pull request. Otherwise you have to rebase.